# 2.7 Terrabyte Partition only 100G in Size

Tags: ubuntu, mount, partition

I've just partitioned and mounted a new 3-terrabyte hard-disk under Ubuntu. Now the size of the partition shows up as 100G only.

`lsblk` command tells me `sdc1` is 2.7 terrabyte

```
root@homecinema-xbmc:~# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0
├─sda1   8:1    0 104.1G  0 /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0
└─sda5   8:5    0   7.7G  0 [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0
└─sdb1   8:17   0   1.8T  0 /media/sdb1
sdc      8:32   0   2.7T  0
└─sdc1   8:33   0   2.7T  0
```

but `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /media/` tells me, `sdc1` is only 100 gigs in size:

```
root@homecinema-xbmc:~# sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /media/
100G    /media/sdc1
1.7T    /media/sdb1
1.8T    /media/
```

Did I miss anything in mounting my harddisk?

Answer (score 3):

`du` shows occupied space. To show the total, use `df`.

Answer (score 3):

`du` is for disk usage; it is showing that you are using 100G. Rather than `du`, use `df -h`; it will report used and available space.